# Indices when reading matrix from file

Tags: fortran

I use the routine READ to read a matrix from a file. Actually, I directly extract 9 submatrices (think of a big 3x3 table, each is a submatrix). The exact indices don't matter, but each submatrix is NY_INTxNY_INT approx, so that the whole matrix in the file is 3NY_INTx3NY_INT.

```
      OPEN (91,file= 'inf/matrix_re.dat',form='formatted',status='old')   
      OPEN (92,file= 'inf/matrix_im.dat',form='formatted',status='old')   
c   
       do i=0,NY_INT-1
           READ(91,*) k11real(i,0:NY_INT-1)
       READ(92,*) k11imag(i,0:NY_INT-1)
       end do
c
       do i=0,NY_INT
           READ(91,*) k12real(i,NY_INT+1:2*NY_INT+1)
       READ(92,*) k12imag(i,NY_INT+1:2*NY_INT+1)
       end do
c
       do i=0,NY_INT-1
           READ(91,*) k13real(i,2*NY_INT+2:3*NY_INT+1)
           READ(92,*) k13imag(i,2*NY_INT+2:3*NY_INT+1)
       end do
C
C
       do i=NY_INT+1,2*NY_INT+1
           READ(91,*) k21real(i,0:NY_INT-1)
           READ(92,*) k21imag(i,0:NY_INT-1)
       end do
c
       do i=NY_INT+1,2*NY_INT+1
           READ(91,*) k22real(i,NY_INT+1:2*NY_INT+1)
           READ(92,*) k22imag(i,NY_INT+1:2*NY_INT+1)
       end do
c
       do i=NY_INT+1,2*NY_INT+1
           READ(91,*) k23real(i,2*NY_INT+2:3*NY_INT+1)
           READ(92,*) k23imag(i,2*NY_INT+2:3*NY_INT+1)
       end do
C
C
       do i=2*NY_INT+2,3*NY_INT+1
           READ(91,*) k31real(i,0:NY_INT-1)
           READ(92,*) k31imag(i,0:NY_INT-1)
       end do
c
       do i=2*NY_INT+2,3*NY_INT+1
           READ(91,*) k32real(i,NY_INT+1:2*NY_INT+1)
           READ(92,*) k32imag(i,NY_INT+1:2*NY_INT+1)
       end do
c
       do i=2*NY_INT+2,3*NY_INT+1
           READ(91,*) k33real(i,2*NY_INT+2:3*NY_INT+1)
           READ(92,*) k33imag(i,2*NY_INT+2:3*NY_INT+1)
       end do
c
```

Is this code right? It seems to me that I am not using the loops correctly.

I don't understand if the indexes in the READ statements are the positions within my destination matrix or the ones from the file I am reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indices that you are calling are based upon the new array that you have created.

A better approach would be to read in all of the values into one array, and then create a new array for each individual sub-matrix, getting the data out of the  array.

```
OPEN (91,file= 'inf/matrix_re.dat',form='formatted',status='old') 
do i = 1, length of all values  
    new_array = read(91, *)
enddo

do i = 1, length of all values
    sub_matrix_1 = new_array[]
    sub_matrix_2 = new_array[] 
    etc..
enddo
```

It of course depends on what you are trying to do with the data afterwards.

Comment: So, i is for each row, right? Also, I get this error: an asterisk is invalid in this context (read(91,*) )

Comment: Yes, it is suppose to be read(91, *) , whatever you reading in. read(91,*) does not stand by itself. Hope this helps :)